# Problem with firebase for authentication of a Google account

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with the **FirebaseAuthentication.NET** library and **Firebase** in itself basically I have this error message which is displayed each time my application wants to connect to **Google**. I'm using WPF .Net Core 3.

[image: The screenshot of the error message in question.]

So I give the authorization on my localhost firebase interface but unfortunately it does not work ;-; especially the problem the library FirebaseAuthentication.Net is not used a lot so I don't know if I'm the only one having this problem!

[image: Image of authorized domain names]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good finally I found the solution basically, must put the entire link is "http://localhost/authorize/" and "http://127.0.0.1/authorize/" on the google cloud console!